# Is it possible to get a list of all open files (and the programs being used to view them)?

Tags: bash

I want to write a script that obtains a list of all open programs and files, and then generates a shell script to re-open these files. For example, if I were editing the file example.txt using gedit, and editing the file myscript.js using geany, I would want to generate a script that could re-open both of these files using their respective programs.  Is there any way to obtain a list of running programs and files from the command line?

Comment: I've used `lsof` before, but I'm not sure that it's comprehensive. (I've used it to see what was preventing me from ejecting a volume, but it sometimes cannot find which file was open.)

Comment: @Sparhawk Will `lsof` output a list of open files (as well as a list of running programs)?

Comment: Here's additional relevant information: http://superuser.com/questions/383342/how-to-get-a-list-of-opened-files-for-a-script-under-linux

Comment: `lsof` does do that. (Give it a go!) Also, I think that `ps aux` is more process oriented, and hence does not list all open files. I don't have gedit on my computer (I use KDE), but when I open a file in kate, the filename is not listed in `ps aux`.

Comment: @Sparhawk See my answer - ps aux lists the running programs as well as the files that are being edited with those programs. (Does lsof list running processes as well as running programs? I specifically need to find the processes that are associated with open programs.)

Comment: I think `ps aux` only lists files that are open if they were arguments of the command used to start the process. If I start kate, then open files from within it, the output of `ps aux | grep [k]ate` is `sparhawk       4606 15.5  0.3 467332 58188 ?        Sl   13:28   0:01 /usr/bin/kate -b`. I'll try `lsof` and print the output.

Comment: Hmmm... `lsof` is certainly more extensive. It does list the process, and then all the files that are open from the process (e.g. shared libraries, fonts), but it doesn't seem to list the test file either. I guess that kate reads the file then immediately closes it. So the text file is not technically "open" any more. Hence, what you are after might not be possible, since some programs might "close" the file immediately after reading it.

Comment: @Sparhawk I opened the file `stuff.txt` with gedit, but then I couldn't find `stuff.txt` or `gedit` in the output of `lsof`. Which command-line arguments for `lsof` did you use?

Comment: I didn't specify any arguments. Like I say, stuff.txt might not be there, but it's surprising that gedit isn't. I'm not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it is not possible to do in the way you're approaching this, because the files opened in a text editor are not "open" in the sense programmers use the term (i.e. "having an active file handle somewhere within the program which can be used for I/O operations"). What most programs do is open the file, read the data in a memory buffer, then close the file. Saving a file is the same - open, write, close. Between open and save operations the file is not "open", it's just the copy of the data in the program's buffer in memory.

So it is generally not possible to figure out which files are currently loaded into the program's memory - however, the *program itself* does know that, so from inside the program it is trivial to implement an option to remember the list of open files on shutdown and re-open those files on startup. Many text editors, for example Kate and Sublime Text 2 do provide such option.

Some desktop environments, such as KDE (and also the old Gnome, I'm not sure about Gnome 3/Unity) also provide an option to save the list of running programs on shutdown and re-launch those programs on startup. Which combined with using a good editor kinda achieves what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is it possible to detect when a file is modified by a specific program (for example, detect when the file `stuff.txt` is modified using the program `gedit`)?

Comment: Yes, there's an API which allows to monitor file access called `inotify`. There's also a command-line tool called `inotify-watch` from `inotify-tools` package.

Comment: Can inotify detect the specific program that a file was modified by (instead of simply detecting file changes?) I'm still not sure if it can detect the specific program that is used to access or modify a file.

Comment: I don't think it can, but for your usage (reinvoking a previous session), can you not just define your default programs properly, then use something like `xdg-open <filename>`.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: "The inotify API provides no information about the user or process that triggered the inotify event." - however, if you monitor the "file open" event you can try using `lsof` to catch the file owner before the editor closes the file :) Although the approach feels very messy. See this for details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file

Answer (score 1):

The command `ps aux` will display a list of running processes. In some cases, it will also list the files that are being edited with those programs, if the file name was used as a command line argument when starting the process. For example, I opened the file `stuff.txt` using gedit, and `gedit /home/anderson/Desktop/stuff.txt` was displayed in the output of `ps aux`.

Comment: It appears that it would be feasible to use the output of `ps aux` to generate a script that could automatically re-open the list of running files (for a specific set of programs, if desired).

Comment: `ps aux` does not show "the files that are being edited with those programs", it shows the command line used to start the program. Which would only work if you do something like `gedit myfile.txt`. It won't work if you started gedit and then used File-Open to open the file.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for the info. I updated my answer.

Comment: It appears that the equivalent of `ps aux` on Windows is `tasklist /v`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of files opened with `gedit` today (July 1, 2020 in this case):

```html
$ grep 2020-07-01 /home/$USER/.local/share/recently-used.xbel

  <bookmark href="file:///mnt/e/bin/scpto" added="2020-06-27T00:32:22Z" modified="2020-07-01T20:09:35Z" visited="2020-06-27T00:32:23Z">
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2020-07-01T20:09:35Z" count="228"/>
  <bookmark href="file:///mnt/e/bin/reset-owner" added="2020-06-30T12:51:15Z" modified="2020-07-01T01:39:20Z" visited="2020-06-30T12:51:15Z">
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2020-07-01T01:39:20Z" count="5"/>
```

Then call `gedit` and pass the filenames to it:

```html
gedit /mnt/e/bin/scpto /mnt/e/bin/scpto
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is trick you can try [may be in gnome]**

this show files opened by a process [may not currently using]

History file

> /home/$USER/.local/share/recently-used.xbel

may help you.

1. First take a copy of *recently-used.xbel*
2. Run process and exit [open file, close it. open file, close it and so on... and exit]
3. now compare *recently-used.xbel* with old *recently-used.xbel*
4. from the diff extract *file name* and *associated process*

For a DEMO just copy paste

`diff <(cat ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel)  <(gedit /tmp/2.txt; cat ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel)`

from the output you can extract filename and process.

Comment: Why do you use gedit in the second redirection? If I use the gedit part for the saved old  recently-used.xbel file, it just did print nothing to the standard output and opens in gedit the file. So what was your idea behind that?:`diff  <(cat ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel)  <(gedit ~/Documents/recently-used.xbel; cat ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel)`. For me it just looks you differ against the same file and the old file. Cause you are using gedit, this somehow does not work...